# Adding gridview line data into textboxes and labels

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, gridview

I'm trying to get the gridview details to be put into textboxes for better view and edit.
I'm listing the following code to create the gridview:

```
'Finds all cases that are not closed
    Protected Sub listAllCases()
        sqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT TC.caseId,TS.subName,TSU.userName,TC.caseType,TC.caseRegBy,TC.caseTopic,TC.caseDesc,TC.caseSolu,TC.caseDtCreated, TC.caseStatus FROM TBL_CASE TC INNER JOIN TBL_SUBSIDIARY_USER TSU ON TC.caseUser = TSU.userID INNER JOIN TBL_SUBSIDIARY TS on TSU.usersubId = TS.subId WHERE TC.caseStatus = 0 order by caseId")
        sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection
        sqlConnection.Open()
        'sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subID", Me.caseSub.SelectedItem.Value)

        Dim dr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
        dr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader
        If dr.HasRows Then
            allCases.DataSource = dr
            allCases.DataBind()
        Else
            allCases.DataSource = Nothing
            allCases.DataBind()
        End If
        dr.Close()
        sqlConnection.Close()
    End Sub
```

Then I use the a function on the gridview onselectindexchanged and Writes this:

```
Protected Sub OnSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim row As GridViewRow = allCases.SelectedRow
        txtcase.Text = row.Cells(1).Text()
        txtsub.Text = row.Cells(2).Text
        txtuser.Text = row.Cells(3).Text
        oDato.Text = row.Cells(9).Text
        lDato.Text = "Saken er ikke lukket!"
        txttype.Text = row.Cells(4).Text.ToString
        txtregBy.Text = row.Cells(5).Text.ToString
        txttopic.Text = row.Cells(6).Text
        txtDesc.Text = row.Cells(7).Text
        txtSolu.Text = row.Cells(8).Text
        lblinfo.Text = row.Cells(6).Text
    End Sub
```

I only get it to display cells 1 to 9. Means cell 4 to 8 is not listed or being blank, even though i know it should contain data.

Any tips or Clues is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. i got it right, finally. the code i used to get it work is as follows:

```
Protected Sub allCases_OnSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim row As GridViewRow = allCases.SelectedRow
        txtcase.Text = row.Cells(1).Text()
        txtsub.Text = row.Cells(2).Text.ToString
        txtuser.Text = row.Cells(3).Text
        oDato.Text = row.Cells(9).Text
        txtDesc.Text = TryCast(row.FindControl("lblcaseDesc"), Label).Text
        txtSolu.Text = TryCast(row.FindControl("lblcaseSolu"), Label).Text
end sub
```

this means I need to fetch the boundfields and templatefields differently.
Anyhow thanks for the reponse.

Answer (score 0):

Like This ?

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
TextBox1.text = DataGridView1.Rows(e.Index).Cells(0).value.toString
TextBox2.text = DataGridView1.Rows(e.Index).Cells(1).value.toString
TextBox3.text = DataGridView1.Rows(e.Index).Cells(2).value.toString
TextBox4.text = DataGridView1.Rows(e.Index).Cells(3).value.toString
TextBox5.text = DataGridView1.Rows(e.Index).Cells(4).value.toString
TextBox6.text = DataGridView1.Rows(e.Index).Cells(5).value.toString
TextBox7.text = DataGridView1.Rows(e.Index).Cells(6).value.toString
TextBox8.text = DataGridView1.Rows(e.Index).Cells(7).value.toString
TextBox9.text = DataGridView1.Rows(e.Index).Cells(8).value.toString
TextBox10.text = DataGridView1.Rows(e.Index).Cells(9).value.toString
End Sub
```

This will display all the information in the row by clicking the record...

Comment: (ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As.....
Could you please finish that? I have already tried with: Private Sub allCases_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles allCases.CellContentClick

but it fails on Handles part. Also the e.index part is not a member of System.Windows.Form.DatagridvireCelleventargs. The .Value is not either in the suggestion Box when i try to find it.

Answer (score 0):

e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

sorry for that ...

by clicking the data the (e.Index) will locate in which DataGridView.Rows(), then the cells.(n) and etc... will get your data

Comment: on the "Handles gridview1.CellContentClick", it just tells me"Event'CellContentClick' cannot be found." I have updated the gridview1 to correct gridview ID.

also the e.index tells me that index is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs.